# Fill down the row of sprites

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, grid, match

I'm working on a prototype of match puzzle game. I'm using Unity. Main mechanic is very simple: grid 7x8 filled with tiles of 5 kinds. When user tap on any tile, it looks for similar adjacent tiles and if there is at least 3 of a kind, then they are removed.

Tiles are regular `GameObject`s with a `SpriteRenderer` component and my script which defines what sprite to load. Also it handles click but all other logic runs on the Grid.

So, I've already done: grid initialization, detecting same tiles and removing them. I'm doing it like that:

```
void RemoveShape() {
        foreach (DashItem item in items) {
            if (item.shouldBeDestroyed) {
                item.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = null;
                item.shouldBeDestroyed = false;
                item.alreadyChecked = false;
            }
        }
    StopCoroutine (FindNullTiles ());
    StartCoroutine (FindNullTiles ());
}
```

As you can see I don't destroy actual GameObject, just setting it sprite to null.

```
public IEnumerator FindNullTiles() { 
        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++) {
                if (items[x, y].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite == null) {
                    yield return StartCoroutine(ShiftTilesDown(x, y));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And now I don't know how to implement `ShiftTilesDown()`.

This method should run through all tiles, check if they sprites == null and shift down to fill the gaps. Then I need to fill top empty sprites.

Thanks

Comment: And the objective of `ShiftTilesDown()` is to....?

Comment: Edited description